# Using QVALUE package: Can i use a p value as a test statistic?

Tags: r, p-value, false-discovery-rate

I have a question about the QValue package in R (see [here](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/manuals/qvalue/man/qvalue.pdf) for documentation).

In the example in 4. Quick Start Guide, the code is this:

```
library(qvalue)
data(hedenfalk)
obs_stats <-hedenfalk$stat
null_stats <-hedenfalk$stat0
pvals <-empPvals(stat = obs_stats, stat0 = null_stats)
qobj <- qvalue(p = pvals)
```

My question: This example works with test statistics, converts them to  pvalues and then makes a qobj based on these.

In my analysis, I do not have test statistics. I have a set of p values, and then 100 sets of simulated p values (i.e. I have a table like this):

```
Gene      ActualPVal   Random.1.Pval    Random.2.PVal    Random.3.PVal  
Gene1      0.01        0.02             0.03            0.04
Gene2      0.4         0.5              0.4             0.3
Gene3      0.3         0.01             0.2             0.3
```

I want to compare the randomised p values to the original p values and gives me back pi0 and local FDR.

The problem, since I already have the p values, I don't need to use empPvals to convert my null and test statistics to p values, so my code looks like this:

```
library(qvalue)
data(hedenfalk)
qobj <- qvalue(p = pvals)
```

...but then using this code, the code only reads in a vector of p values and does not read in the randomised p values at all.

So in this case, is it just that my "test statistic" happens to be a p value, my "null statistics" are also p values, and then I run:

```
pvals <-empPvals(stat = obs_stats, stat0 = null_stats)
```

Where obs_stats is a set of observed p values, and null_stats is a matrix of random p values?

Sorry if this is confusing; basically; is it acceptable for a p value itself to be considered a test statistic, against which you can check significance with randomised p values (other test statistics) to obtain FDR rates/q values?